# Adding a new SQL Server connection in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm using `SQL Server 2005` and `Visual Studio 2010`.

So, the problem... When I try to add a new data connection to Visual Studio I receive the folowing error message:

> Unable to add data connection. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Sql.Server.Management.Sdk.sfc, Version = 10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: How are you adding the data connection?

Comment: Can you post your connection string? You connected to existing SQLServer or just to the datafile?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 is version 9.00 and the message above point to SQL Server 2008(Ver10.00) for what its worth. ;)